# Cocoapods1.3.2 Xcode8 pod install Generating Pods project Abort trap: 6

Tags: installation, cocoapods, xcode8

192:podss etcxm$ pod install --verbose
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-podss`: (``)

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A FMDB

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing FMDB (2.6.2)

> Copying FMDB from
>     `/Users/etcxm/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/FMDB/2.6.2-854a0` to
>     `Pods/FMDB`
>     - Running pre install hooks
>   Generating Pods project
>     - Creating Pods project
>     - Adding source files to Pods project
>     - Adding frameworks to Pods project
>     - Adding libraries to Pods project
>     - Adding resources to Pods project
>     - Linking headers
>     - Installing targets
>       - Installing target `FMDB` iOS 4.3
>       - Installing target `Pods-podss` iOS 8.0
>     - Running post install hooks
>     - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
>       - Generating deterministic UUIDs
>   Abort trap: 6

I've tried reinstall cocoa pods, but not succeed.

Comment: yaojy this is Cocoapods's pre-relase version : 1.1.0.rc.3? What is 1.3.2? it's hard to understand your question, please add your pod file

Comment: yea,Cocoapods's pre-relase version : 1.1.0.rc.3,    xcodeproj is 1.3.2 ,               ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768)     ,                                               rvm 1.27.0 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]    ,                                         192:kkkNew etcxm$ gem sources -l
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
http://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
https://gems.ruby-china.org/

Comment: please share your pod file for help us to fix your problem?

Answer (score 15):

My solution was:

Removing all cocoapods gems:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-search
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-stats
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-try
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk
```

Then installing latest pre release version:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Comment: This also helps, when you have macOS developer preview

Answer (score 4):

First uninstall Ruby 2.3.1, and install [version 2.2.5](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/releases/tag/v2_2_5), and after that reinstall cocoapods may resolve your issue.

Please try, and let me know if it's fix your problem.